# Parsing JSON using Dart and Start framework

Tags: json, dart

I'm trying listen to a `PUT` request on the server-side with Dart and I've chosen the [Start framework](https://github.com/lvivski/start) and now I'm kind of stuck with this.

Assuming I have this code on the server :

```
class Games {
  Future<Server> startGamesServer() {
    List<Game> games = [];

    return start(port: 3010).then((Server app) {
      print("Starting http server");

      app.put('/games').listen((Request request) {
        request.payload().then((value) => print("hello")); <-- HERE
      });
    }
}
```

And I'm doing the following request with Postman:

target url: `localhost:3010/games`

request method: `PUT`

body with type JSON: `{"hello":"world"}`

I've tried using the `Request` object provided by the framework but it won't work with some `RangeError` exception in the `payload()` function:

`Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: RangeError: index (1) must be in the range [0..1)`

```
  Future<Map> payload({ Encoding enc: UTF8 }) {
    var completer = new Completer();
    _request.transform(const AsciiDecoder()).listen((content) {
      final params = new Map.fromIterable(
          content.split('&').map((kvs) => kvs.split('=')),
          key: (kv) => Uri.decodeQueryComponent(kv[0], encoding: enc),
          value: (kv) => Uri.decodeQueryComponent(kv[1], encoding: enc) <-- Fails here
      );
      completer.complete(params);
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
```

It doesn't even print "hello"... I feel like I'm not using the `Request` object properly, according to the docs :

`put // adds a handler, returns a Stream<Request>`

*Request*

```
header(String name) // get header
accepts(String type) // check accept header
input // raw HttpRequest stream
path // requested URI path
uri // requested URI
cookies // provided cookies
param(String name) // get query param by name
payload(Encoding enc) // get a promise with a Map of request body params
```

*Response*

```
header(String name, [value]) // get or set header
get(String name) // get header
set(String name) // set header
type(contentType) // set Content-Type
cache(String cacheType) // set Cache-Control
status(code) // sets response status code
cookie(name, val) // sets cookie
add(string) // add a string to response
close() // closes response
send(string) // sends string and closes response
json(Map data) // stringifies map and sends it
jsonp(String name, Map data) // stringifies map and sends it in callback as `name(data)`
render(viewName, [Map params]) // renders server view
```

Is there a way to get the actual json map from the query? I'd like to have a dart map with the following content:

```
{ "hello" : "world" }
```

edit: I've got "{hello: world}" printed by doing this:

```
app.put(GAMES).listen((Request request) {
  print("put");
  request.input.listen((data) {
    print(JSON.decode(new String.fromCharCodes(data)));
  });
});
```

I don't know if it's the best way though.

Comment: Did you try to `print(content);` before `final params`?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, since the `payload()` method isn't mine (it's Start's)... When I try to edit the file, it won't let me (from IntelliJ)

Comment: I see. I think I understand your question now but have no idea what could solve the problem. Maybe you have a better chance of getting a response by creating an issue in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Yeah maybe. I've got the hello world thingy, but I think it's kind of tedious no? I'm coming from the Java world where everything is auto-converted into objects, and now I have to decode String characters haha!

Comment: Java uses Streams a lot too.

Comment: Yes but behind the scenes no? Isn't there a library that does all that in Dart? (at least converting an httpRequest body into a json map or something like that..)

Comment: It's a while that I used Java but my experience regarding streams was quite similar (may have changed because it's a while back). It's only to allow you to pass the transformer you actually want to use. Not everyone sends/receives only JSON. You can wrap the code in a method and pass it instead to avoid repeating this code (I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for).

Comment: If you want auto-conversion between objects and JSON , you might be better off with the [Redstone framework](https://github.com/luizmineo/redstone.dart) which handles this via [Redstone Mapper](https://github.com/luizmineo/redstone.dart/wiki/redstone_mapper).

Comment: I second the suggestion of using the Redstone framework - I think it's much better in terms of what it offers over Start (I've tried both), and the documentation is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending JSON you can't use that function because it looks like it's parsing formdata/key-value pairs from the response.

Usually it should be `JSON.decode(content)['hello']` but your framework does not offer something like this.